# Error while installing MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I was trying to install mysql in ubuntu. I applied following command for it

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

But got the following error.

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me to solve the error.

Comment: please post the output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Output of sudo dpkg --configure -a is dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server and output of sudo apt-get install -f is Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: there are some broken packages. I am not a pro at ubuntu but I remove my broken packages using synaptic manager. This is the process: http://askubuntu.com/a/166949

Answer (score 3):

Doing this solved it for me:

`sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get install mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

seems like there's an error with one of the packages being installed or that quite never installed properly in the past.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642173

here is a link that helps identify the package and how to correct it.

Comment: Using the command given in above link I got following error E: Unable to locate package getdeb-repository

Comment: Like @Deep and link mentioned, run the following commands `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f` to see what package has an issue , then run `sudo apt-get remove --purge <PACKAGENAME>`

Comment: Even after doing that same error exists when I run the command again. Please help me to solve the problem

Comment: try `apt-get clean` that will remove all the packages causing you to download them again if you need them for a new installation. then try to install again. If that doesn't remove the package you couldn't install and its dependencies and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try given commands.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-client-core-5.6
    sudo apt-get autoremove
    sudo apt-get autoclean
    sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
    sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

[Try this link](http://dbadiaries.com/how-to-install-mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-lts)

Comment: After trying the above link got the following error 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.41-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1). Please help me to solve this

Comment: Yes I tried and got following error after trying first one  mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem And with this method, the problem was solved

**1**-Get the list of MySQL packages installed on the system by executing the command

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep mysql
```

**2**-Remove the the packages shown above by executing the command

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove <packages from the step 1>
```

**3**-Delete /var/lib/mysql
**4**-To add MariaDB repository to Ubuntu, run the commands below to install the repository key to your system.

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
```

**5-**

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu '$(lsb_release -cs)' main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/MariaDB-10.2.list"
```

**6**-After that, run the commands below to install the latest version of MariaDB.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

**7**-

```
cd /var/run
sudo cp mysqld/ mysqld.bc -rf
sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld.bc/
sudo service mysql stop
sudo cp mysqld.bc/ mysqld -rf
sudo chown mysql:mysql mysqld -R
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

**8**-Now  able to log in database using

```
mysql -u root
```

**9**-Then to update root password:

```
UPDATE user SET authentication_string=password('YOURPASSWORDHERE') WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```